# How to make a "mutable" number in an array (numpy)?

Tags: arrays, numpy, reference

I am trying to make an array, which includes the same number multiple times, but if I change it in any place, it should change everywhere. Like with lists:

```
a = b = [1]
>>> a.append(1)
>>> print(b)
>>> [1, 1]
```

So I want an array like this:

```
number = 10   
arr = numpy.zeros((10, 10))
arr[0][0] = number
arr[1][1] = number
arr[0][0] += 1
print(arr[1][1])
```

Here it should output "11". So is there a way to have multiple references to a number? I know you could replace all the 10s with 11s, but firstly this would be too inefficient, secondly this could mess things up since another number may be coincidentally a 10 too.

Thanks.

Comment: As long as the new positions are strided stepsize away, you can create views. A more representative sample (more number of places where the new number should be changed) could clarify things.

Comment: Try to use `arr[0,0]` style indexing on  arrays.  It's safer than `arr[0][0]`.

Answer (score 1):

A zero dimensional numpy array behaves in many respects like a mutable number:

```
>>> import numpy as np                                                  
>>>                                                                                                                 
>>> a = 2.0            # ordinary immutable number
>>> am = np.array(2.0) # "mutable number"                                                                                          
>>>                                                                                                                 
>>> A = np.array([[a, a, am, a], [am, am, a, a]], dtype=object)
>>> A
array([[2.0, 2.0, array(2.), 2.0],                                                                                  
       [array(2.), array(2.), 2.0, 2.0]], dtype=object)
```

That's a bit ugly, so below I'll convert to float before printing:

```
>>> A.astype(float)                                                          
array([[2., 2., 2., 2.],                                                                                            
       [2., 2., 2., 2.]])
```

These twos are not all equal, The top left is immutable

```
>>> A[0, 0] += 1
```

Assigning to it only directly addressed cell is affected:

```
>>> A.astype(float)
array([[3., 2., 2., 2.],
       [2., 2., 2., 2.]])
>>> a
2.0
```

The third two is mutable

```
>>> A[0, 2] -= 1
```

Assigning to it all references are affected:

```
>>> A.astype(float)
array([[3., 2., 1., 2.],
       [1., 1., 2., 2.]])
>>> am
array(1.)
```

Direct assignment requires `[()]` syntax:

```
>>> A[0, 2][()] = 1.5
>>> am
array(1.5)
```

Otherwise the link will break:

```
>>> A[0, 2] = 1.8
>>> A.astype(float)
array([[3. , 2. , 1.8, 2. ],
       [1.5, 1.5, 2. , 2. ]])
```

### Update:

In a comment OP specifies the following desired behavior:

If the mutable number `am` occurs `k` times in `A`, then in `A * 3` the mutable number should be multiplied with `3**k`, not `3`.

We can get this behavior using the inplace (`*=`) operator and some trickery; if we want to preserve the original `A`, we must first make a copy:

Because `numpy`s copying machinery normalizes our 0D arrays away, some more trickery is required to make a good copy:

```
>>> import copy
>>>
>>> B = np.empty_like(A)
>>> B.ravel()[...] = copy.deepcopy((*A.ravel(),))
```

Now do the inplace multiplication on the copy:

```
>>> import operator as op
>>> 
>>> C = np.frompyfunc(op.imul, 2, 1)(B, 3)
>>> 
>>> A
array([[2.0, 2.0, array(2.), 2.0],
       [array(2.), array(2.), 2.0, 2.0]], dtype=object)
>>> C
array([[6.0, 6.0, array(54.), 6.0],
       [array(54.), array(54.), 6.0, 6.0]], dtype=object)
```

Note that `B` will contain some useless hybrid data in the end and should be discarded.

```
>>> B
array([[2.0, 2.0, array(54.), 2.0],
       [array(54.), array(54.), 2.0, 2.0]], dtype=object)
>>> del B
```

Final note: this is more trickery than sane programming, so please regard it as a can-be-done rather than a should-be-done.

Comment: This gets pretty close to what I want, but I think what I want (as described in a comment to the other answer) is impossible

Comment: @NoBody Did I hear "impossible"? Please check out the updated answer.